# Call for a column through 'for" loop

Tags: r

In my data frame I have columns named A1,A2,A3..A400. I would like to get the mean of certain columns using 'for' in a way:

```
for (i in c(6,7,11,44)) {mean(mydata$A"i")}
```

Thanks for any tip.

Comment: use `mydata[, paste0("A",i)]`, note that this can be done without a loop also. The loop is not efficient.

Comment: To complete @RLave comment above, have a look at `colMeans`

Comment: With `library(dplyr); mydata %>% summarise_at(vars(paste0("A", c(6,7,11,44))), mean)`

Answer (score 0):

to summarise the comments you can avoid the loop by using.

```
colMeans(mydata[,colnames(mydata) %in% paste0("A", c(6,7,11,44))])
```

You first select the relevant columns and then compute the means using `colMeans`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cols <- c(6,7,11,44)
means <- sapply(cols, function(x) mean(df[, x]))
```

This is even simpler:

```
means <- sapply(df[, cols], mean)
```